# The type or namespace name 'IAuthenticationFilter' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, namespaces

I have a class library and I have added the reference to **System.Web.Mvc** v4.00 but for some reason the **Filters** namespace is unavailable. 
I am trying to create a custom controller and I have used **ILSpy** to look at the existing class. It has a reference to **System.Web.Mvc.Filters** which I can see when I inspect the assembly but in my project there appears to be no **Filters** namespace.

Does anyone have any idea why?

Cheers.

Comment: Isn't `IAuthenticationFilter` new since Mvc 5?

Comment: yeah, but the assembly version is 4 (at least in my project it is)

Comment: Is this a runtime or compile time error? Are you running the app locally?

Comment: Well, if it's new in Mvc 5 it does not exists in 4, so that's the reason for the error.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same issue.  With the Nuget package manager I had installed the latest MVC 5.2.3 version on the project, but still had the error.  With the Nuget package manager it showed that I had indeed had the MVC 5.2.3 but looking in the reference I found that the runtime version was 4.0 and the version was 4.X

I solved the issue by unchecking the box in the Nuget package manager and clicking "OK". This takes MVC out of the project.  Then I went back into the manager and installing it again.

Worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

I have just faced the same issue but after i find that i have not imported the name space System.Web.MVC.Filters. After adding this my issue got resolved. You don't need to worry about the runtime version of system.web.mvc

Comment: Its worked for me - Un install package(MVC 5.2.x) and re-install again